# Android 7.0 - Torch Will Not Work With Camera

Tags: nexus-5, camera

I have a Nexus 5X running Android 7.0. Every few months I have to photograph some meters that are in a dark location. These used to be read manually with a torch but now I have to submit photographs. I used to turn on the Nexus torch and take photographs without flash. This worked well but since a recent update of the camera app the torch goes out when I turn the camera on. Using flash generates glare and unclear photographs. Is there any way around this? Trying to hold an additional torch is proving near impossible because of the awkward access.

Comment: At the moment I am getting around it by taking short video clips as the torch then stays on. This seems to highlight a general problem in that Apps get updated and if there is an issue you cannot go back to the previous version as far as I can tell. Previously I have back ported on Linux and this is what is really needed...